# mysql sum of 2 select

Tags: mysql, sum

I have mysql question:

This table stores information about the films that have been converted.
This is my first sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uzytkownicy_filmy WHERE id_uzytkownika =1341143 AND id_albumu=0
```

This table stores information about the films that have been added and wait for their queue d conversion , the conversion are transferred to the table uzytkownicy_filmy
This is second:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uzytkownicy_filmy_convert WHERE id_uzytkownika =1341143 AND id_albumu=0
```

And the question is:

how i can connect two result and give into my sql queries:

```
        UPDATE uzytkownicy_filmy_albumy
        SET ile_filmow=(

        // Here I want the sum of the queries that you see above 

                       )
            WHERE id="' . $this->oDb->getSecureForm($iAlbumId) . '" AND id_uzytkownika="' . $this->oDb->getSecureForm($iUserId) . '"');
```

Comment: Can we pretend that `uzytkownicy` is `users`?

Comment: uzytkownicy is users -> but it's only name of table

table name in English:
`users_movie`
`users_movie_convert`
`users_movie_albums`

Comment: I know. Some people here are very good (amazing, even) at thinking in the abstract. I'm not. I like to think in more concrete terms. I know it's silly, but because I think in English, I can hang on to the idea of a `user` more easily than a `uzytkownicy` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that sums both queries is the following:

```
SELECT a.count + b.count FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM uzytkownicy_filmy WHERE id_uzytkownika =1341143 AND id_albumu=0) AS a,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM uzytkownicy_filmy_convert WHERE id_uzytkownika =1341143 AND id_albumu=0) AS b;
```

so you can just add this code snippet in that final query of yours:

```
UPDATE uzytkownicy_filmy_albumy
    SET ile_filmow=(

        SELECT a.count + b.count FROM
           (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM uzytkownicy_filmy WHERE id_uzytkownika =1341143 AND id_albumu=0) AS a,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM uzytkownicy_filmy_convert WHERE id_uzytkownika =1341143 AND id_albumu=0) AS b;

                   )
        WHERE id="' . $this->oDb->getSecureForm($iAlbumId) . '" AND id_uzytkownika="' . $this->oDb->getSecureForm($iUserId) . '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the sum of the two count, something like this should do the work:

```sql
DECLARE @SUM1 INT,
        @SUM2 INT
SELECT @SUM1 = COUNT(*) FROM uzytkownicy_filmy WHERE id_uzytkownika =1341143 AND id_albumu=0
SELECT @SUM2 = COUNT(*) FROM uzytkownicy_filmy_convert WHERE id_uzytkownika =1341143 AND id_albumu=0

UPDATE uzytkownicy_filmy_albumy
    SET ile_filmow=(

    // Here I want the sum of the queries that you see above
    @SUM1 + @SUM2

                   )
        WHERE id="' . $this->oDb->getSecureForm($iAlbumId) . '" AND id_uzytkownika="' . $this->oDb->getSecureForm($iUserId) . '"');
```